# Updating css animation-name with js and the animation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, animation, styles

I have one problem, i want to when a button is clicked an animation is made. **CSS CODE:**

```
img {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  right: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes Loading {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

And this is my **JS CODE:**

```
function Loading() {
document.querySelector("img").style.animationName = "Loading";

setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector("img").style.animationName = "";
}, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Your code [works](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/7ogkfz6n/).

Comment: idk, maybe it has smth to do with my code left (full website)

Comment: Could you put a snippet into your question which shows the problem as I can’t see anything wrong with the code you have provided so the problem must be elsewhere e.g. in the way you are calling Loading.

Comment: The webpage contains personal info so i can't do that, but do you know any reason this could happen?

Comment: Most likely, you have more than 1 `<img>` element in your website. `document.querySelector('img')` returns the first `<img>` in DOM. Why not give your image a unique `id` and use `document.getElementById('your-unique-id')`?

Comment: i tried with getElementById and still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

I just found the problem, the problem was that the img parent had some properties: display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center. I removed that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use object.style.WebkitAnimationName for Chrome, Safari, and Opera and animationName for other like this:

```
document.querySelector('.objectName').style.WebkitAnimationName;
document.querySelector('.objectName').style.animationName;
```